# How to print the content of one of the columns related to the same user just using awk?

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I have columns like these:

```
User    ColumnA  ColumnB  ComumnC
abc123  hi       hello    howdy?
xyz123  Namaste  que paso rowdy?
abc123  hi       hello    bowdy?
```

I want to write the gawk script which prints the content in column 3 related to just abc123 like the following:

```
User: abc123
    howdy?
    bowdy?
```

So far I got this:

```
gawk '/^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}/ { 
    temp=$1
    printf ("User:  %s\n", $1); 
    printf ("\t %s\n", $4)
}' $1
```

But it prints all the user and their content in column C in every line without merging the same user's content in columnC like this.

```
User: abc123
    howdy?
User: xyz123
    rowdy?
User: abc123
    bowdy?
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to group the output by user per yr example, just for user `abc123`  or for all users showing up in yr example ? Also in yr wanted-output example, the question mark at the end of field $4 disappeared. Is that what you want ? We need this level of precision to offer you a solution.

Comment: My bad, the output does not need to delete question mark. Let me edit it. Thanks.

Comment: Oops Sorry, it should do the treatment for all the users and print out in the specified format. The example above is just an excerpt of the output required.

Comment: What @Alessiosavi answered is working jest a little more `echo User":" $user && cat users.txt | grep $user | awk '{  print $4}'`this should give you what you need about the formatting of the output

Comment: This should put you on the way to finding the solution (it needs a little work still): `awk 'NR>1 {++a[$1]; b[$1][a[$1]] = $NF} END {for (i in a) {printf "\nUser: %s\n",i; for (j in b[i]) {printf "\t%s\n",b[i][j]} }}' datafile`  where `datafile` contains yr input, as shown in OP, but without column names.

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '
NR>1{
    if(!o[$1]) {o[$1]="User: "$1"\n\t"$4}
    else {o[$1]=o[$1]"\n\t"$4}
}
END { for (i in o) print o[i] }
' file
```

Output:

```
User:abc123
    howdy?
    bowdy?
User:xyz123
    howdy?
```

Comment: Very neat. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Well done, pLumo! Much simpler than what I was pointing at in my comment.  One thing though; even with `-F'\t'` `$NF` is safer than `$4` in this case. You can never be too sure that input file data columns are tab delimited and not space delimited.

Comment: @PrashantSedhain, perhaps you should consider **_accepting_** that solution with the green check in the left margin.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are:

```bsh
# Save the filename
filen="test.txt"
# Save the column name
col_name="$(head -n1 $filen|awk '{print $1}')"
# Save the target word
to_find="abc123"
echo "$col_name: $to_find" ; for name in $(grep $to_find $filen | awk '{print $4}'); do echo "  $name"; done
```

Text example:

```
User    ColumnA  ColumnB  ComumnC
abc123  hi       hello    howdy?
xyz123  Namaste  que paso rowdy?
abc123  hi       hello    bowdy?
```

Output:

```
User: abc123
  howdy?
  bowdy?
```

Comment: The print need to be 4 that was
What he wants to print.

Comment: You don't need `cat` as `grep` already prints to standard output.

Comment: Edited, i usually write script as more didactic as i can, avoid optimization for enhance readability for new user